# Does a force field absorb hit point damage from an attack that would only deplete stamina points?

Tags: equipment, hit-points, starfinder

In Starfinder, personal force fields grant temporary hit points to the user and fast heal those temporary hit points every round for a finite number of rounds. My question is whether the force field provides any protection at all from an attack that would only deplete the target's stamina points?

If the force field itself had a number of hit points that it would absorb before damage was applied to the user (like a ship's shields), this would be a simple question--damage would be applied first to the force field and extra over that round's allotment would be applied to the user's stamina points and then hit points. But the description of the force field states that it grants temporary hit points to the user and if the user is a player character then they do not lose hit points (temporary or otherwise) until their stamina points are depleted. It seems to me that, rules as written, force fields do not protect stamina points, but since attacks that reduce stamina points do in fact hit the character, a force field *should* protect them. Am I reading the rules right or am I missing something? Has Paizo clarified this at all?

Comment: Have you seen this [temporary HP](https://www.aonsrd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=124)?

Comment: I did. Just wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything before posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You apply damage to your temporary HP first.** You apply damage to your stamina points only after your temporary HP are depleated.

You are probably missing the rules on [temporary HP](https://www.aonsrd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=124).

> Certain effects, such as force fields, give you temporary Hit Points. These Hit Points are in addition to your current Hit Points and Stamina Points, and **any damage you take is subtracted from your temporary Hit Points first. Any damage in excess of these temporary HP reduces your Stamina Points** (and then your actual Hit Points) as normal. If the effect that grants the temporary HP ends or is counteracted, any remaining temporary HP go away.

Thus you  apply damage to your temporary HP first then if there is any excess damage you apply it to your stamina points (if any) and after that to your normal HP.

Comment: Yep, I read those rules too long ago and not thoroughly enough. Thanks.